# Im trying to make a decimal to binary number without using bin

Tags: python, binary

So im trying to make a decimal to binary convertor in python without using the bin
and this is incomplete, but for now im trying to get 'a' as a list with all the factors that led to the conversion
for example if the decimal inputed = 75,
then 'a' should be = [64, 8, 2, 1]

Can someone tell me how to correct my code

but i seem to be running into a error which ive given below the code

```
q3 = float(input("Enter a number: "))

def raise_to_power(base, power):
    result = 1
    for index in range(power):
        result = result * base
    return result

def decimal_to_binary(decimal):
    num1 = 2
    count = 1
    x = 0
    a = list([])

    while num1 <= decimal:
        if num1 < decimal:
            num1 *= 2
            count += 1
        x += 1
        decimal = decimal - num1
        a[x] = raise_to_power(2, count)
        num1 = 2
        count = 0
    
    return a
        
decimal_to_binary(q3)
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/veresh/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Binary_Num Convertor.gyp", line 34, in <module>
    decimal_to_binary(q3)
  File "/Users/veresh/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Binary_Num Convertor.gyp", line 28, in decimal_to_binary
    a[x] = raise_to_power(2, count)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to positions in a list that don't exist.

Instead of

```
a[x] = raise_to_power(2, count)
```

add the result to the list using [list.append](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

```
a.append(raise_to_power(2, count))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with fewer steps.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
b = []
while num > 0:
    b.append(num%2)
    num = num//2

f = [(2*a)**i for i,a in enumerate(b) if a != 0]
f = f[::-1]
print (f)
```

This will give you the following result:

```
Enter a number: 75
[64, 8, 2, 1]

Enter a number: 36
[32, 4]

Enter a number: 29
[16, 8, 4, 1]
```

Comment: maybe change `while True` to `while num > 0` ?

Comment: You can click the green checkmark to accept the answer. If you are able to upvote, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it recursively:

```
def decimal_to_binary(inp):
    power = 1
    tmp = 1
    while 2**power <= inp:
        tmp = 2**power
        power += 1
    if inp-tmp != 0:
        return [tmp] + decimal_to_binary(inp-tmp)
    else:
        return [tmp]

print(decimal_to_binary(75))


[64, 8, 2, 1]
```